# BadTokenException Unable to add window (ProgressDialog)

Tags: android, compiler-errors, progressdialog

I got BadTokenException error when I create a ProgressDialog in my application. I tried read a few post regarding about the issue, I still can't really get what's the cause of it. I call the dialog function after I click on a button.

```
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DIALOG_LOADING:
        dialog = new Dialog(this, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent);          
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.loading);
        break;


    default:
        dialog = null;
        break;
    }
    return dialog;  
};
```

The above code is my progress dialog code. I call it with just this `showDialog(DIALOG_LOADING);` Can anyone kindly tell me what causes this and how to overcome the issue? Any comments will be appreciated.

```
12-18 12:12:39.250: E/AndroidRuntime(7654): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-18 12:12:39.250: E/AndroidRuntime(7654): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@4057a200 is not valid; is your activity running?
12-18 12:12:39.250: E/AndroidRuntime(7654):     at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:532)
12-18 12:12:39.250: E/AndroidRuntime(7654):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:200)
12-18 12:12:39.250: E/AndroidRuntime(7654):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:114)
12-18 12:12:39.250: E/AndroidRuntime(7654):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
12-18 12:12:39.250: E/AndroidRuntime(7654):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
12-18 12:12:39.250: E/AndroidRuntime(7654):     at   android.app.Activity.showDialog(Activity.java:2566)
12-18 12:12:39.250: E/AndroidRuntime(7654):     at android.app.Activity.showDialog(Activity.java:2524)
12-18 12:12:39.250: E/AndroidRuntime(7654):     at com.fl.wbillboard.Web_Input$1.onClick(Web_Input.java:128)
12-18 12:12:39.250: E/AndroidRuntime(7654):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2538)
12-18 12:12:39.250: E/AndroidRuntime(7654):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9152)
12-18 12:12:39.250: E/AndroidRuntime(7654):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-18 12:12:39.250: E/AndroidRuntime(7654):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-18 12:12:39.250: E/AndroidRuntime(7654):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
12-18 12:12:39.250: E/AndroidRuntime(7654):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
12-18 12:12:39.250: E/AndroidRuntime(7654):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-18 12:12:39.250: E/AndroidRuntime(7654):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-18 12:12:39.250: E/AndroidRuntime(7654):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
12-18 12:12:39.250: E/AndroidRuntime(7654):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
12-18 12:12:39.250: E/AndroidRuntime(7654):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Sure. I should have put it in. My bad. I have included it in the question.

Comment: What line is `Web_Input.java:128`? The call to the onCreateDialog method?

Comment: Web_Input.java line 128 is `showDialog(DIALOG_LOADING);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use activity's reffrence for show dialog..

use this `new Dialog(activity_name.this, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent);`  instead of  `new Dialog(this, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent);`

```
case DIALOG_LOADING:
        dialog = new Dialog(activity.this, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent);          
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.loading);
        break;
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I guess maybe I should better include activity_name as well. But still in this case, it doesn't solve my issue. Any idea what might cause the error?

Comment: is this activity is child of any other activity if yes then use getParent() instead of activity.this

Comment: Only one window can be added to a activity at a time example keyboard is also a window added to a activity if your dialog appears  when any other  window is present in your activity this causes the BadTokenException and you should also pass the activity on which your dialog shld appear

Comment: Thank you everyone for dropping answers and comments. Apparently is because I'm using this under a Tab, that's the reason that I get BadTokenException for using `this` instead of getParent(). Thank you JaiSone, CapDroid and Lochana Ragupathy for the comments.